# Should I use static import?

Tags: java, import

How important it is to convert all my import to `static import`? Why are people still reluctant to use `static import`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good use case for static import of methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420791/what-is-a-good-use-case-for-static-import-of-methods)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the docs say, use it [sparingly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).  Look there for the justifications.

Comment: Good answer, never thought checking the source!

Answer (score 9):

This is a special case but also the perfect use case (and I use it in all my tests):

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;
```

Here, I find that this makes my tests more readable and it's obvious from where `assertXXX` come from. But this is an exception. In other situations, I find that static import make things more obscure, harder to read and I don't really use them.

Comment: Before I switched to using Spock, I went 1 step further: `public class MyTestClass extends junit.framework.Assert { ... }`. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 5):

I use static import when working with JUnit's assert (`import static org.junit.Assert.*;`) and also when I have an `enum` that is very tied to the class in question.

For example:

Enum file:

```
public enum MyEnum {
   A, B, C;
}
```

Class file:

```
import static MyEnum.*;

public class MyClass {
  MyEnum e;

  public setE(MyEnum newE) {
    if ( newE == A ) {
       // some verification
    }
    e = newE;
  }
}
```

Note how I was able to do `newE == A`, instead of `newE == MyEnum.A`. Comes in handy if you do a lot of these throughout the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, never use wildcard static imports.

Without wildcarding, on the as needed basis, I think it does reduce the clutter.

Answer (score 1):

I use a `static import` only in the most glaringly obvious situations.  Remember: concise code is not always the same thing as readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `static import` is preferred if you are using an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all important to convert existing working code, in fact it's just a needless cost and risk.

You can consider using it for *new* code, if you can find a compelling use for it. I haven't yet, but I may ...