# Mockito methods are not accessible

Tags: mockito

I have mockito setup on my project with this maven lines:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have no problems to use the `@Mock` annotation but I can't access and use mockito methods like:

```
when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn();
```

Eclipse just does not recognize them.

Please help.

Comment: Have you included the right static imports?

Comment: import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

Comment: yes. I imported org.mockito.* .  still does not work

Comment: I noticed that there is no org.mockito.Mockito.* - no another Mockito library inside

Comment: Please don't misread my comment.  Did you add the exact line that I wrote in my earlier comment?  Or something different?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try calling `Mockito.when(foo.getBar()).thenReturn(baz)` and `Mockito.verify(foo).getBar()`, which won't rely on static imports. Unlike the `@Mock` annotation, which is technically a class, `when` and `verify` are static methods on the Mockito class.

Once you have that working, then try the static imports to which David alluded:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;   // ...or...
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;      // ...with the caveat noted below.
```

This will then allow you to use `Mockito.when` without specifying the `Mockito` class. You can also use a wildcard, as so, but per [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2791970/1426891) the [Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) recommend using wildcards sparingly--especially since it can break if a similarly-named static method is ever added to Mockito later.

Adding `import org.mockito.*;` is insufficient because that adds all classes in the `org.mockito` package, but not the methods on `org.mockito.Mockito`.

For Eclipse in particular, you can add a static import by putting the cursor on the `when` part of `Mockito.when` and pressing Control-Shift-M ("Add import"). You can also add `org.mockito.Mockito` to your Favorites (Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites > New Type) so that all Mockito static methods show up in your Ctrl-Space content assist prompt even if you haven't imported them specifically. (You may also want to do this for org.mockito.Matchers, which are technically available on org.mockito.Mockito via inheritance, but may not show up in Eclipse for that reason.)

Comment: +1 for the extra tip on content assist: addition of org.mockito.Matchers because of the inheritance problem

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin syntax - dont forget the ` ` backticks:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`


`when`(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn();
```