# The method when(BasePersistenceImpl<capture#2-of ?,Long>) is undefined for the type BusinessServiceImplTest

Tags: mockito, powermock

I am getting error 
"The method when(BasePersistenceImpl) is undefined for the type BusinessServiceImplTest"

here  is my code sample

when(PersistenceFactory.getService(RecordTypeEnum.CANDIDATERESPONSE, mockEntityManager)).thenReturn(mockCandidateResponsePersistenceImpl);

public static BasePersistenceImpl getService(
            RecordTypeEnum eNum, EntityManager entityMgr)
            throws ADRDataAccessException {}

Please let me know if I missing syntax

thanks

Comment: Do you `import static org.mockito.Mockito.when` with the rest of your imports?

Comment: Yes I did PowerMockito.mockStatic(PersistenceFactory.class);

Comment: That's not the same thing: I'm referring specifically to the _imports_. It looks like you're missing the `import static` line above. See also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14089770/1426891), which describes a similar problem.

Comment: thanks that's resolved now with import. Some thing the error should tell missing import...