# Correct use of static imports in java

Tags: java, import, static-import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good use case for static import of methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420791/what-is-a-good-use-case-for-static-import-of-methods)

I rarely ever see a static import in java like this:

`import static java.lang.Math.*;`

Then you could access `PI` without having to call `Math.PI`.

Since you don't see this that often, does that mean it is a bad design to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer not to use them, simply because I want to see where each constant is defined. If your classes and your constants are named appropriately, it helps readability a lot.

Then again, if you're using a lot of constants from the same class and it's obvious where they come from, you're better off with a wildcard import.

Answer (score 2):

It is not bad design, but in my opinion `Math.PI` is clearer for maintaneinance than just `PI`.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes yes.  When you use a static import, the fields and methods from the class you statically imported might "look like" they come from *your* class.

This does impact understandability, IMHO.

That said, I use it all the time in JUnit tests!

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad. It's just usually not necessary. I personally use it whenever my program uses a lot of calls to `java.lang.Math`.

Most people also don't know about it since it's so infrequently used. Same thing goes to other constructs like static constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Math was around before `import static` which is why most developers would tend to use the older form.