# Small problems splitting a string

Tags: java, string, split

I have this string:

```
"http://my/website/collections/index.php?s=1&schema=http:/my/web/fe7cd50991b11f51050902sddaf3e042bd5467/idApp=19"
```

I want to extract this token from the string: `fe7cd50991b11f51050902sddaf3e042bd5467`

the website can vary, but the only think cannot vary is that the string token i must obtain  always is on the left of "/idApp="

Which is the most efficient way to solve that?

thanks.

Comment: What're the ones that you've tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String url = "http://my/website/collections/index.php?s=1&schema=http:/my/web/fe7cd50991b11f51050902sddaf3e042bd5467/idApp=19";
String[] tokens = url.split("/");
String searched = tokens[array.length - 2];
```

This will work if the token is everytime the prelast. Otherwise you need to go through the `Array` and check if the current token matches your condition and take the token before.
In code:

```
int tokenId = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  if (token[i].equals("/idApp=")) {
    tokenId = i - 1;
    break;
  }
}
String rightToken = tokens[tokenId];
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the token can only numbers and letters, you can use something like this.

It matches a sequence of numbers and letters, preceding the /idApp= string.

It is "efficient" in terms of being a standard, easy-to-read way to do that, but there may be more performance-efficient ways to do it, although you should think carefully about whether finding this string would really be a performance bottle-neck.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class TestRegexp {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String text = "http://my/website/collections/index.php?s=1&schema=http:/my/web/fe7cd50991b11f51050902sddaf3e042bd5467/idApp=19";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)/idApp=");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regexp here. Absolutely. The task is just to cut a piece of string, don't over-complicate. Simplicity is the key.

```
int appIdPosition = url.lastIndexOf("/idApp=");
int slashBeforePosition = url.lastIndexOf("/", appIdPosition - 1);
String token = url.substring(slashBeforePosition + 1, appIdPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex

These two packages will help you

- `java.util.regex.Matcher`
- `java.util.regex.Pattern`

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your answer and provide the OP with a solution, rather than talk about available packages only :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple 2 times split would work for multiple parameters. First split on `"idApp"` and then on `/`.

The following code would work even if there are multiple parameters after the `idApp` parameter.

```
String url = "http://my/website/collections/index.php?s=1&schema=http:/my/web/fe7cd50991b11f51050902sddaf3e042bd5467/idApp=19";
String[] tokens = url.split("idApp");
String[] leftPartTokens = tokens[0].split("/");
String searched = leftPartTokens[leftPartTokens.length - 1];
System.out.println(searched);
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing anything with strings, always look to:

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Here is my answer...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Don't forget: import static org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.*;
    String url2 = "http://my/website/collections/index.php?s=1&schema=http:/my/web/fe7cd50991b11f51050902sddaf3e042bd5467/idApp=19";
    String result =  substringAfterLast("/", substringBeforeLast(url2,"/")) ;
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Though the answer is completely valid, I wouldn't advise the OP to use static imports. [What is a good use case for static import of methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/420791/851811)

Comment: You're correct, the static import is not necessary but in my opinion it keeps the code less verbose and most IDE's will tell us where the code originates from. I normally do a static import of the StringUtils as I would tend to use it heavily and Oracle says "use it when you require frequent access to static members from one or two classes.".