# How to Separate the String in the java for the below requirement?

Tags: java, string

need to separate the string,i need to separate it.The String is dynamically add.

For Example

```
1.String a="C:\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Media Server 2.2.3\content\user2\weight.mp4"
```

i need to separate it **user2**

```
2. String a="C:users\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Media Server 2.2.3\content\user2\sample.flv"
```

So i added the value dynamically for **a**, but i need to separate the string before **weight.mp4**  after **content** .

Comment: What do you need to do to the String?

Comment: i need to get the path of the video

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12277301/1103412) to a similar question here on SO.

Comment: kindly See my questions clearly each and every time my string s differ according to this,How can i separate,from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277246/small-problems-splitting-a-string/12277301#12277301 question,the string is static not dynamic

Comment: I'm not sure if I correctly understood your question but I thought you needed to extract the name of the folder in which the file (directly) resided. If that's the case, you could use the same approach as T.Grottker described in his answer to the other question. You might also use the [File class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to easily extract the folder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to substring the sequence between two last slashes. Look at methods 'lastIndexOf' and 'substring' of String class.

Answer (score 1):

You Can approach like also..

```
String s="C:/Wowza Media Systems/Wowza Media Server 2.2.3/content/user2/weight.mp4";
String strArray[]=s.split("/"); 
String fileName = strArray[strArray.length-1]; /*weight.mp4*/
int index = s.indexOf(fileName); 
String path = s.substring(0,index) /*C:/Wowza Media Systems/Wowza Media Server 2.2.3/content/user2/*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Are tried something like this?

```
a = a.replace("users", "");
```

It's kinda hard for me to explain because i don't know to much what are you trying to do.
Is it only avoiding "users" or adding or you try to do something more?

Comment: hai grachol,,,i need to separate the string before weight.mp4 after *content* .thats my requirement

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to fetch the file name from that String. If so:

If you have your String a defined like this:

```
String a="C:\\Wowza Media Systems\\Wowza Media Server 2.2.3\\content\\user2\\weight.mp4"
```

try the code:

```
String[] split = a.split("\\");
String file = null;
if(split.length!=0) file=split[split.length-1];
System.out.println(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String end = a.substring(a.lastindexof("\\"),a.length); // <- get the end
String tmp = a.substring(0,a.lastindexof("\\"));  // <- get the rest
String start = tmp.substring(0,a.lastindexof("\\"); // <- get the start
```

I'm shure the code above have some syntax errors and in the first line you have to add 1 to the lastindexof perhaps. But it gives you an idea to solve your problem.