# What is static imports and what is its importance in java

Tags: java, import, static

While reading some java books, I came to know about static imports.
I have some doubts in my mind.

1. What is static imports.
2. When and why to use it.

Explaination with examples will be helpful.

Comment: Didn't that Java book gave you an example? What doubt are you having about them?

Comment: Also did you try to google "java static import"? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html

Comment: Read the java books some more.  If they are any good, they will explain it.  Or this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html

Comment: Yes, I read upon static imports, but why to use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420791/what-is-a-good-use-case-for-static-import-of-methods

Answer (score 1):

One example is JUnit tests

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
 ...
 assertEquals(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Imports are typing shortcuts.  A "regular" import is a shortcut down to the class level...

```
import java.util.List
```

Let's you just use

```
List l;
```

Instead of

```
java.util.List l;
```

A static import is a shortcut down to the method level.  The method must be static, since there is no instance to associate with it...

```
import static java.lang.Math.abs
```

Lets you just use

```
x = abs(y);
```

instead of

```
x = java.lang.Math.abs(y);
```

Imports do not effect your compiled output or running code in any way.  Once something is compiled there's no way to tell if the original source had imports or not.