# Eclipse import shortcut does not work as expected

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I was writing the Junit code below in eclipse kepler. I pressed the shortcut `ctrl+shift+o` to automatically import all the packages that are needed by this code. The shortcut only imported Test and gave me an error in assertEquals - `The method assertEquals(int, int) is undefined for the type FootballTeamTest`

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class FootballTeamTest {

    @Test
    public void constructorShouldSetGamesWon() {
        FootballTeam team = new FootballTeam(3);
        assertEquals(3, team.getGamesWon());

    }

}
```

This was fixed by adding an import `import static org.junit.Assert.*;`. Why does eclipse not do this import automatically ?

Related post - [What is a good use case for static import of methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420791/what-is-a-good-use-case-for-static-import-of-methods)
Go to the answer for Junit4 in that question. Amazing.