# Static import Long.parseLong in Java

Tags: java, static-import

Today in private method I used `Long.parseLong()` (just once in whole class) with some `String` as value. At peer review colleague wrote that this method should be `static import` and then called without `Long.`. I asked why because as I know and what is in https://stackoverflow.com/a/421127/4952262 in such case we should just go with `Long.parseLong()` instead of trying to save 5 characters. The answer was that `parseLong` method is just in `Java.lang.Long` package and it's safe because this method was, is and will be just in this package. Is it good way? Does it really make a code more readable?

Comment: I'm not sure there's an industry position on this issue; it's mostly a style and/or preference decision.  The "correct" answer typically is this:  be consistent within the codebase

Comment: There is some redundancy because parseInt, ParseLong, parseDouble reside exactly in Int, Long and Double respectively, and it could shorthen arithmethic expressions. However I have never used it, or (I admit) seen it. Whereas I have seen many static imports in unittests.

Comment: Static imports should indeed be used very sparingly, but `parseLong` is _probably_ ok unless there is any risk your company might write their own parseLong method to do something else. As an antipattern example, I've worked at a place where it was a guideline to statically import _everything_. We had code that said `of(...)` and we couldn't tell if it was Stream.of, Date.of, Instant.of, List.of, or anything. It made me puke every time I saw that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how do you infer it, I have read a lot about it that static imports increase the code readability. 
But let's think of a scenario where you have two classes namely Class A and B.
Think that both the classes have similar static fields/method that you want to use in some third Class C. 

Now how does it increase the readability of code ?

Again i am not arguing where its wrong or correct to use static imports but yes i do believe in some of the cases it sounds good to do so in other it might not.

**Note :**  Anyways it does not make any difference when it comes to performance as much as i know.